# Admob's native ad intercepts touch events from fragment

Tags: android, admob, fragment

I have a problem with native ad: I want to use it in the fragment, that appears over my activity. Then user should swipe fragment from the screen with native ad on it. My fragment shows and hides with a swipe fine, my native ad block shows fine, but I cant make a swipe inside the native ad. I can swipe outside of ad only - just on fragment's space. So, native ad inercepts all touch events and nothing happens.
How can I make native ad to listen my swipes and leave clicks for its work as advertisement? I would like a user could swipe my fragment even by swiping on the ad block so far.

Native ad uses a template

```
 AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd nativeAd) {
                        // Show the ad.
                        Log.d("serg", "loaded");
                        NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(background).build();
                        TemplateView template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                        template.setStyles(styles);
                        template.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
                    }
                })
                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                        Log.d("serg", "fail"+adError.toString());
                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                        .build())
                .build();

        // Creating  an Ad Request
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build() ;

        // load Native Ad with the Request
        adLoader.loadAd(adRequest);

// listening for touch events
View ad_fragment = findViewById(R.id.ad_fragment);
        ad_fragment.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                //
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(
                                R.anim.slide_in,  // enter
                                R.anim.slide_right_out  // exit
                        )
                        .hide(fragment1)
                        .disallowAddToBackStack()
                        .commit();
                toggleShowed = 0;

            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (toggleShowed == 0) {
                   
                } else {
                    
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(
                                    R.anim.slide_in,  // enter
                                    R.anim.slide_left_out  // exit
                            )
                            .hide(fragment1)
                            .disallowAddToBackStack()
                            .commit();
                    toggleShowed = 0;
                }
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                //
            }
        });
```

Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".AdFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="gravity = center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Ad"
            android:textColor="#FFDD00"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

        <!--  This is your template view -->
        <com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
            android:id="@+id/my_template"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_medium_template_view" >

        </com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
            android:name="ru.shutochki.AdFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: NativeAdView intercepts every touch event on top of it, elevation does not work also. Nothing can't done on my own